# how to change the date time in a text file with todays date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a json file. In that file, I have to replace the date and time with today's date and time. How can I do this? This is my file data.
In this data i have to replace '2017-01-8--15-59-10' into today's data.
again tomorrow I have to replace that data with tomorrow's date.

i tried this but it is not working

```
var newFName = Regex.Replace(str, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"), DateTime.Today("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"));
```

this is my data which i want to edit

```
string data=@"where POSBill.CreatedOn between 2017-01-8--15-59-10 and @addedtimestamp order by POSBill.CreatedOn limit 2000"
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use another query parameter like `@addedtimestamp` instead and pass the desired DateTime value? This would be the recommended way to compose a query anyway.

Comment: that i can not use because service will start 2 or 3 times per day so next time also i have to change the date and time

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding on how query parameters work. You should provide a [mcve] showing why in your case, you cannot use a parameter holding the current DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can save in a table time your job start (or end if you prefer),

And in next job run, you take data from this table.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data string seems to represent a database query that already uses a query parameter (`@addedtimestamp`) you can simply add another query parameter passing the desired value:

```
string data = @"where POSBill.CreatedOn between @today and @addedtimestamp order by POSBill.CreatedOn limit 2000"
```

... when using your query string, just provide a value for this parameter the same way you do for the already existing parameter `@addedtimestamp`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", DateTime.Today);
```

This will offer a the dynamic behavior you intend and spare you the complicated string replacement.